# Identify unique model programmatically

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How can you identify a model in the viewer programmatically? i.e. what parameters of the model can help differentiate between different models?

What I tried:

`viewer.model.id` always returns 1.

`viewer.model.myData.basePath` or `viewer.model.myData.urn` is just a string of a path and one model can potentially take the same path of another at a later time.

Hashing more unique values like `packFileTotalSize` and `primitiveCount` in `viewer.model.myData` could give closer to 1 to 1 ids, but it's more of a hack.

Is there a hash, name or model id that's more likely to be unique to one model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy way to handle that is to tag the model yourself right after you load it, here is how I do it in my app:

```
const onModelLoaded = (model) => {

      model.guid = guid()
}

viewer.loadModel(path, loadOption, onModelLoaded)
```

Here is my implementation for guid() function:

```
guid (format = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx') {

  var d = new Date().getTime()

  const guid = format.replace(
    /[xy]/g,
    function (c) {
      var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0
      d = Math.floor(d / 16)
      return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x7 | 0x8)).toString(16)
    })

  return guid
}
```

This is just an example, you could replace guid by some value from a database record or some other source. I am assuming that you know from where your model is coming from at the time of the loading.

Comment: If I'll load that model again later, it'll get a new and different guid, I wanted to have it stay the same.

Comment: As I said, this is just an example of the approach I am using in my app to uniquely identify models which can be loaded in multiple occurrences of the same root file. If you need an identical guid for the same model, you may use the model URN directly, which is guarantee to be unique and will remain constant. If you are loading the model based on some database record information, you could use the record Id or a unique identifier precomputed in the database ...

Answer (score 0):

If you store your file on OSS, you can request the [file details](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-details-GET/), and get its SHA1 code. Unfortunately, this is the only place today (time of this post) you got a SHA1 hashcode returned by the API.

Comment: And if I don't use OSS?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only place today (time of this post) you got a SHA1 hashcode returned by the API. We logged a bug on this, but it is not yet fixed and released.